# Multi Translator for Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

does anyone know how to make translate multi language page in codeigniter, some plugin or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a language library, however if you need to render large amounts of text it could be easier to store user langue as a session variable and get DB information based on the language. 
[Language library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)